# add text just below or above every image in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

```
 private static void InsertTextToPdf(string sourceFileName, string newFileName)
        {
            using (Stream pdfStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
            using (Stream newpdfStream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newpdfStream);
                PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
                pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);
                pdfContentByte.BeginText();
                pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Kevin Cheng - A Hong Kong actor", 400, 600, 0);
                pdfContentByte.EndText();
                pdfStamper.Close();
            }
        }
```

This code is working fine to add text in a PDF , but i want to add the same text on below of every image in PDF.

I tried with merging the code of image extraction with text add but not able to see the same text multiple time , while able to see multiple image extraction. I added the text in same  loop where extracting the image  .

```
public static Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image> ExtractImages(string filename, string sourceFileName, string newFileName)
        {
            var images = new Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Image>();
            Stream newpdfStream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            using (var reader = new PdfReader(filename))
            {
                //
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(reader);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newpdfStream);
                PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
                var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
                ImageRenderListener listener = null;
                for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    parser.ProcessContent(i, (listener = new ImageRenderListener()));
                    var index = 1;
                    if (listener.Images.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var pair in listener.Images)
                        {

                            images.Add(string.Format("{0}_Page_{1}_Image_{2}{3}",
                                System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename), i.ToString("D4"), index.ToString("D4"), pair.Value), pair.Key);

                            index++;


                            {

                                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                                pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
                                pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);
                                pdfContentByte.BeginText();
                                pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Kevin Cheng - A Hong Kong actor", 400 + index * 10, 600, 0);
                                pdfContentByte.EndText();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                pdfStamper.Close();
                return images;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IRenderListener` implementation `ImageRenderListener` you try to use collects the images in a `Dictionary<System.Drawing.Image, string>` mapping images to the file extension matching their original type. In particular it completely ignores the image coordinates and, therefore, is not usable for your task to *add text just below or above every image in pdf*.

Instead you need an `IRenderListener` implementation which calculates the coordinates of the position atop an image; you can actually go a step further and even do the text adding in that listener, e.g. this implementation:

```
public class ImageEntitlingRenderListener : IRenderListener
{
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
    int page = 0;

    public ImageEntitlingRenderListener(PdfStamper pdfStamper, int page)
    {
        this.pdfStamper = pdfStamper;
        this.page = page;
    }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        Matrix ctm = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();
        float xCenter = ctm[Matrix.I31] + 0.5F * ctm[Matrix.I11];
        float yTop = ctm[Matrix.I32] + ctm[Matrix.I22];
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(page);
        pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
        pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);
        pdfContentByte.BeginText();
        pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "rahul", xCenter, yTop, 0);
        pdfContentByte.EndText();
    }

    public void BeginTextBlock() { }
    public void EndTextBlock() { }
    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
}
```

This render listener adds "rahul" atop each bitmap image in your PDF.

*Beware: I kept the code simple by introducing some assumptions. In particular I assumed the images in the PDF to be rendered upright and no page rotation to be involved. A generic solution would have to consider the whole `ctm` and the page rotation when calculating `xCenter`, `yTop`, and the text rotation (here always `0`).*

You can use that render listener like this:

```
private static void InsertTextToPdf(string sourceFileName, string newFileName)
{
    using (Stream pdfStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
    using (Stream newpdfStream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newpdfStream);

        var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);
        for (var i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            parser.ProcessContent(i, (new ImageEntitlingRenderListener(pdfStamper, i)));
        }
        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
}
```